# How to use 'page-break-before or after' on PrimeNG table?

Tags: javascript, angular, css

when I use something like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div></div>
        <div style="page-break-before:always; background-color: blue"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

(add to my primeNG table) I decided to add `background-color:blue` to see waht's happend. It is very strange to me and I really don't know how to fix it. I lost almost 1-2 weeks to solve this and nothing... I tried many examples -> nothing. I wrote many questions -> nothing. I still hope that someone can help me.

This is the example:

[image]

Why I have "double" page-break, why this blue thing is on the whole page?

Answer (score 0):

The PrimeNG table already does automatic page break, so it seems like that's conflicting and causing it to have two page breaks now.